# JavaScript Date in this format: "Wednesday, March 03, 2010 05:44:15 PM"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display date like this in my website "Wednesday, March 03, 2010 05:44:15 PM".

If I use JavaScript it will take lengthy code. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be interested in the [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library.

You can easily try it out by including the datejs script in your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js"></script>
```

You can then use `toString()` method to format the date as required:

```
new Date().toString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");

// returns "Wednesday, March 03, 2010 01:40:18 PM"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can format it in the server side.